# How to dynamically populate svelte-simple-modal component?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, svelte, sveltekit

I have the following in my `Modal.svelte` file:

```html
<script>
  import Modal from "svelte-simple-modal";
  import { modalState } from "$lib/stores";

  const imports = {
    Person: () => import("./modals/Person.svelte")
  };
</script>

<Modal>
  {#if $modalState.open}
    {#await imports[$modalState.type]() then module}
      <svelte:component this={module.default} />
    {/await}
  {/if}
</Modal>
```

And this is what is in my `stores.js` file:

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

export const modalState = writable({
  open: true,
  type: "Person",
});
```

This renders the contents of the passed `modalState.type` file (which is `modals/Person.svelte`) perfectly, but the content isn't nested in the `Modal` element whatsoever. There is no popup, no close button, and no greyed-out background.

How do I make sure the contents of the imported component are part of the `Modal` and not just added to the page like a non-modal component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this solved by making the following changes to the `Modal.svelte` file:

```js
<script>
  // @ts-nocheck
  import { writable } from "svelte/store";
  import Modal from "svelte-simple-modal";
  import { modalState } from "$lib/stores";

  const modal = writable(null);
  const imports = {
    Person: () => import("./modals/Person.svelte")
  };

  $: if ($modalState.open) {
    (async () => {
      const module = await imports[$modalState.type]();
      modal.set(module.default);
    })();
  }
</script>

<Modal show={$modal} />
```

Additional information can be found in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/flekschas/svelte-simple-modal/issues/90).

Answer (score 1):

The API of that package is fairly unintuitive. The `Modal` either is used as a scope that can be interacted with via a context, or by using a special `bind` function and passing the resulting component to `show`.

It does *not* show the contents of the `Modal` in the dialog.

E.g. with `bind`:

```html
<script>
    import Modal, { bind } from 'svelte-simple-modal@1.4.1';
    import Popup from './Popup.svelte';

    let modal = null;
    $: open = modal != null;
    const showModal = () => modal = bind(Popup, { message: 'Surprise' });
</script>

<Modal show={modal} on:close={() => modal = null} />
<button on:click={showModal}>Show modal</button>

{open ? 'Opened' : 'Closed'}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b93627831cd044b3aed299bda39757f2?version=3.53.1)

You could rewrite the store to directly return a compatible component for `show` or use something like `derived` to return a component dependent on `open`.